# What do the "dumpling hunters" mean in that blog?

Tags: meaning

I've read a blog and there were some "dumpling hunters" mentioned.
I've no clue what does it mean. Googling gave no results.

> The social activities that did form (beer brewing, **dumpling hunters**, board games, joggers) were naturally separate from work. Nobody’s career depended on participating.

https://hackernoon.com/for-inclusive-culture-maybe-less-is-more-87b663662cea

Could you please clarify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never heard this term before, but I interpret it as referring to people who really enjoy dumplings. I know some people who are quite particular about their dumplings, and could tell you a dozen places to get them in order of preference. Dumpling hunters would just be people who like to try new dumpling restaurants, searching for the perfect one.

I'll also point out that that parenthetical list in the text you quote is poorly written, as it ignores parallel structure. Neither "dumpling hunters" nor "joggers" are activities as the leading text suggests, in contrast to "beer brewing" and "board games". It should be written "(beer brewing, dumpling hunting, board games, jogging)".

Answer (score 4):

Dim Sum is:

> a style of Chinese cuisine (particularly Cantonese but also other varieties) prepared as small bite-sized portions of food served in small steamer baskets or on small plates.  ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dim_sum))

It consists in large part of dumplings such as [ha gao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Har_gow), [shumai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shumai), and [XLB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiaolongbao) (my favorites).

So dumpling hunting would be the sport of trying different dim sum restaurants in search of the best dim sum.  There is at least one site dedicated to this:
 [Dumpling Hunter, The search for the world's best dumplings](https://dumplinghunter.wordpress.com/).